# .qcp -> .mp3 on a Mac?

Tags: audio, conversion

My phone records in Qualcomm PureVoice (blech!).

I have nothing, including mplayer and VLC, that plays that.

I'd like to be able to convert them batchwise (so I can grab them via bluetooth) to mp3 (or any other format) on my Mac.

Thoughts?

Here's a [sample file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/529474/1116110822a.qcp) to play with. [Here is that file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/529474/1116110822a.mp3) converted to mp3 using [Online Convert](http://www.online-convert.com/) for reference.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example .qcp file for me to work with?

Comment: That file requires login to download.

Comment: Updated with links to good files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) will do it. It can read qcp files, and it works from the command line so batching is easy:

```
cd /your/directory/of/qcp/files/
for i in *.qcp; do
   ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i/qcp/mp3}" 
done
```

You could tweak the audio settings like setting your bitrate to 128k with "-ab 128k" or "-ar 44100" and suchlike, or you could change the file type by changing "mp3" to whatever you need.

If you're a'feared of compiling ffmpeg and muckign around with the terminal you could try [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/), it might do it. I can't download the sample so I can't test it.

Comment: Have you tested this? For me at this version https://gist.github.com/1367773 it reports that it's an unknown format.

Comment: I'm having the same results as Tim. Unknown file format.

Comment: Finally got ffmpeg through brew working and this now works. [version info](https://gist.github.com/1636930)

Answer (score 1):

Latest VLC does know how to play .qcp files. You can then use the wizard to export as something else. Me, I'd like to find something that will just give it the proper wrapper. You can change the filename extension to .wav, and VLC will still open it up. But QuickTime Player 7 Pro won't...  It's just raw samples, no header. Apparently it's 16bit, 8KHz sample rate mono. But... big endian or little? It should just need a proper header so that QuickTime will see it as a normal .wav.

Comment: `Version 0.9.8 Grishenko (Intel)` still seems to be unable to play, did you test this?

Comment: VLC (latest) crashes when I try to open a qcp file